# Face Detection in J2ME

Tags: java, image-processing, mobile, java-me, face-detection

This is my first time on stackoverflow asking questions so I will try my best to describe what I want to the best of my ability.

I am doing a mobile application that involves taking a picture and detecting the faces of the people in the image.
My target device is on a nokia s40 device which uses J2ME.

I have thoroughly searched the web for sources. 
These are what I got:

1) **OpenCV** (Does not support J2ME, the closes is Java)

2) **JJIL** (J2ME supported, but it lacks documentation, I totally don't understand how I should go about doing it)

Have anyone tried JJIL on J2ME successfully?
I am looking for simple tutorials that can get it working in a day or 2.
Looks like the net has insufficient documentation on J2ME whereas other languages are pretty straight forward.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds far too complicated to be taking place in a J2ME app, I recommend sending the image over the network to a server, doing the face recognition there then sending the results back!

Comment: Why is it too complicated? Can't a J2ME app handle it? Sorry I developing a J2ME app for the first time. Thanks for your answer :)